# Get the defaults programs

Tags: c++, qt

i use c++ and qt for a project.
I would to know how i can get the default program : default navigator, default mail client, default editor ...

I found for Linux - Gnome: gconftool!

What is for Windows, Mac Os or Linux (KDE) ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows this kind of stuff can be recovered directly from the registry (regedit).

Search the web to find out the specific registry paths, like [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6325458_configure-browser-using-regedit-xp.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) you will see that:

> If a mailto URL is specified, the
>   user's e-mail client will be used to
>   open a composer window containing the
>   options specified in the URL, similar
>   to the way mailto links are handled by
>   a Web browser.

So using [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) you should be able to open both the *default navigator* and *default mail client*.

I assume you want to open these applications and not just find out what they are.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft you should not use the registry directly.
See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx